# Gazebo tag <disableFixedJointLumping> didn't work

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to apply force torque sensor plugin in a fixed joint in Gazebo. I am trying to use the tag

```
<disableFixedJointLumping>true</disableFixedJointLumping>
```

But It didn't work.

```
<gazebo reference="FT_Top_Joint_right">
  <provideFeedback>true</provideFeedback>
  <disableFixedJointLumping>true</disableFixedJointLumping>
</gazebo>

  
<gazebo reference="FT_Top_Joint_right">
      <provideFeedback>true</provideFeedback>
   <disableFixedJointLumping>true</disableFixedJointLumping>
</gazebo>



<joint name="FT_Top_Joint_right" type="fixed">
   <origin xyz="0.00085087 -0.00087515 -0.0030305" rpy="3.1416 5.017E-16 1.5708" />
  <parent link="FT_right" />
  <child link="FT_Top_Plate_right" />
  </joint>
```

---

```
[FATAL] [1483501801.768755712, 0.347000000]: gazebo_ros_ft_sensor plugin error: jointName: FT_Top_Joint_right does not exist
```

So I found that **disableFixedJointLumping** didn't work.

I know that the  **"disableFixedJointLumping"** option has been solved here [osrf/sdformat/pull-requests/133/added-urdf-gazebo-extension-option-to/diff](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/pull-requests/133/added-urdf-gazebo-extension-option-to/diff), but I still don't know how to update the urdf_parser.

I am using the OS: **Ubuntu 14.04** ,   ROS version: **indigo**  ,    Gazebo version: **2.2**

Ben

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251231/gazebo-tag-%3Cdisablefixedjointlumping%3E--didn%27t-work/) by [linhongbin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28950/linhongbin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-01-03

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `disableFixedJointLumping` option was added in sdformat 2.0, while Gazebo 2 uses sdformat 1.x [1].
If you want to use the `disableFixedJointLumping` option, please use a more recent version of Gazebo as documented in http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions .

[1] : http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/lists/ros-indigo-trusty-amd64_trusty_main_amd64_Packages

---

Originally posted by [Silvio Traversaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/4782/silvio-traversaro/) with karma: 56 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2023-05-13**:
What is the option for Gazebo 9?